# Bootstrap Popover need to style data-original-title

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Created a popover in bootstrap that has a title (data-original-title). How can I make it bold?

```
<td class="setWidth concat"><div class="boldTitle"><a href="#" class="tip" rel="popover"             data-trigger="hover"  data-content="Hypercholesterolemia is a condition characterized by very high levels of cholesterol in the blood. Cholesterol is a waxy, fat-like substance that is produced in the body and obtained from foods that come from animals (particularly egg yolks, meat, poultry, fish, and dairy products). The body needs this substance to build cell membranes, make certain hormones, and produce compounds that aid in fat digestion. Too much cholesterol, however, increases a person's risk of developing heart disease." 

data-original-title="Hypercholesterolemia">

<span style="cursor:pointer;">Hypercholesterolemia</span></a></div></td>
```

Fiddle Link http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/8J5w6/1/

Comment: please provide a [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/)

Comment: Won't let me sign up give me error "Input error: Invalid referer" This is just HTML code all I want to do is style data-original-title="Hypercholesterolemia">, the word Hypercholesterolemia in bold.

Comment: If I go to fiddle from a google search it will let me make an account. Here it is thank you. http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/8J5w6/1/

Comment: You can add external resources in jsfiddle too. Answer coming.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are three possibilities to achieve your goal.

1. Use `data-html=true` and wrap your title in a `<strong>` element

   ```
   <a href="#" class="tip" rel="popover"
      data-trigger="hover" data-content="Hypercholesterolemia..."
      data-original-title="<strong>Hypercholesterolemia</strong>"
      data-html="true">Hypercholesterolemia</a>
   ```

   [**DEMO with data attribute**](http://jsfiddle.net/w3j8p/)
2. Use `html: true` when initializing and wrap your title in a `<strong>` element

   ```
    $('[rel=popover]').popover({ html : true });
   ```

   [**DEMO with popover param**](http://jsfiddle.net/VzH9P/)
3. Change the appearance of **ALL** popover titles with CSS

   ```
   .popover .popover-title {
       font-weight: bold;
   }
   ```

   [**DEMO with general popover css**](http://jsfiddle.net/xB6hR/1/)

Comment: The last one #3 works and is the easiest. .popover-title {
 font-weight: bolder;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that worked for my project (Bootstrap 4.3.1):

Use html tag `<b></b>` and put `data-html="true"` attribute.

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/