# Add style to data-original-title in jQuery attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip, title

I want to make parts of the title bold and make it multiline. Is there anyways I can do that?

This is my current code:

```
$('.size .card-text').text(siFormat(size_avg).replace(/G/,'B')).attr('data-original-title', 
      "yoyoyo: " + Math.round(size_avg))
```

Currently the result is:

yoyoyo: 3.35

I want it to be:

**yoyoyo:**

3.35

Comment: wrap it using span

Comment: You can't put markup in titles. Use a plugin like `qTip`.

Comment: @PranavCBalan Can you please give me an example?

Comment: @noosigh `<span style="color:red">text :</span>`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Cani I add that in `attr`?

Comment: @PranavCBalan, I am not... just plain old javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, there are choices for you to make, as mentioned in older post:

[style data-original-title](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22091662/1945030)

I think in your case, you may use another attribute: `data-html=true`